# Display images present on server using PHP

Tags: php

I need to display images on web page from the folder present on server.
I tried this:

```
$dir = 'images';
$file_display = array ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');


if (file_exists($dir) ==false) {
echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found';
} else {
$dir_contents = scandir($dir);


foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
    $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));

    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
    echo '<img class="photo" src="', $dir, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '" />';
    }
}
}
```

It didn't work, so I made some changes and tried this:

```
$dir = 'images';
$file_display = array ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');


if (file_exists($dir) ==false) {
echo 'Directory \''. $dir. '\' not found';
} else {
$dir_contents = scandir($dir);


foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
    $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));  \\ERROR

    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
    echo '<img class="photo" src="'. $dir. '/'. $file. '" alt="'. $file. '" />';
    }
}
}
```

But there was an error "only variables should be passed by reference", so I tried:

```
$dir = 'images';
$file_display = array ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');


if (file_exists($dir) ==false) {
echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found';
} else {
$dir_contents = scandir($dir);


foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {

    $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
     $tmp = explode('.', $file);   \\CHANGED THIS LINE
     $file_type = end($tmp);  \\CHANGED THIS LINE

    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
    echo '<img class="photo" src="', $dir, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '" />';
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas how to display images present on server using PHP dynamically?

Comment: When you say "it didn't work" - can you be more specific? Error msgs? Any sort of output?

Comment: Define "didn't work".  I mean, "how to display images" is simply to get the files from a folder, iterate over them in a loop, and build `img` tags which refer to them.  It looks like you're doing exactly that.  How is it failing?

Comment: end/explode is massively wasteful. why not `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`?

Comment: Yeah - but the combination of "end" and "explode" sounds cool when you read it. Very apocalyptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my projects I used RecursiveDirectoryIterator and RegexIterator that will take care on multiple folders inside images directory and create a array of valid files(that matches the regular expression, in our case files with extension jpg|jpeg|png|gif)

```
<?php
$folder = 'images';
try {
    $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(realpath($folder));
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
    $files = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Invalid Directory: ".$e->getMessage();
}
//$files is an array with file name of all the valid images
if(isset($files) && $files != null){
    foreach($files as $filepath => $value){
        echo "<img src='".$filepath."'><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps